# how to sum values in sql using case based on color value?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

As we can see in the image in the color columns there are two values red and black

I want to count both red and black values `Black=3` & `Red=7`

[image]

My Sql query

```
select SPDNO,Cost,Company_Name,Product,Color,
case when Color='Black' then 'sum Black Color' when Color='Red' then 'sum Red Color'
else '' End as ColorResult  
from bike_details where (Color='Red' or Color='Black') and  SPDNO='5000';
```

My Desired output like this given below in single row

```
SPDNO   Cost     Company_Name  ColorSum    Product                                                                                                                       
5000    470000   Memon Motors  3,7         SUPER STAR (SS-70cc)M.C Red,SUPER STAR (SS-70cc)M.C BLack
```

Any Help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 levels of aggregation.
This will work for Mysql:

```
select t.SPDNO, t.Cost, t.Company_Name, 
       group_concat(t.Product order by t.ColorSum desc), 
       group_concat(t.ColorSum order by t.ColorSum desc)
from (
  select SPDNO, Cost, Company_Name, Product, Color, count(*) ColorSum
  from bike_details 
  where (Color='Red' or Color='Black') and  SPDNO='5000'
  group by SPDNO, Cost, Company_Name, Product, Color
) t
group by t.SPDNO, t.Cost, t.Company_Name
```

Comment: i need single row output but its gives me three rows

Comment: Your expected results show 2 rows. Edit your question.

Comment: What is the database that you use?

Comment: ```'5000', '47000', 'Memon Motors', 'SUPER STAR (SS-70cc)M.C Black,
                                  SUPER STAR (SS-70cc)M.C Red,
          SUPER STAR (SS-70cc)M.C Red', '6,3,1' ``` this is the output i m receiving but why product red is appearing two times

Comment: mysql database i m using

Comment: Because in your sample data the color red is given to 2 different products. Check it

Answer (score 0):

`select SPDNO,Cost,Company_Name,Product,Color, SUM(IIF(Color = 'Black', 3, 7)) as ColorResult   from bike_details where (Color='Red' or Color='Black') and  SPDNO='5000' GROUP BY SPDNO,Cost,Company_Name,Product;`

As long as you're only looking at these 2 colors, this will work, otherwise you'd have to do something else.

This is essentially using the [SUM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function against the result of the [IIF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

I just re-read your question and I'm not sure if you're actually wanting to sum the color vlueus or not. If so, you could just remove the SUM() function:

`select SPDNO,Cost,Company_Name,Product,Color, IIF(Color = 'Black', 3, 7) as ColorResult   from bike_details where (Color='Red' or Color='Black') and  SPDNO='5000' GROUP BY SPDNO,Cost,Company_Name,Product;`

Comment: why did u give static valeus in if clause?

Comment: How do you know Umair uses SQL Server?